# In R, replace a value with NA based on matches of a character in an adjacent colunm

Tags: r, replace

I have a data frame with measured data (tmax, tmin) that I would like to replace with NA if a quality assurance code ("G","I","O","S","Z","T") is found in the corresponding row of the adjacent columns (qflag_tmax, qflag_tmin).

A reproducible example,

```
set.seed(1234)
df<-data.frame(
  id = 1:12,
  tmax=floor(runif(12,min=32, max=95)),
  tmin=floor(runif(12,min=0,max=32)),
  qflag_tmax=sample(c("G","I","O","S","Z","","NA"),12, replace=TRUE),
  qflag_tmin=sample(c("G","I","O","S","T","","NA"),12, replace=TRUE),
               stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

For example, I want to replace the observation in tmax with NA if on the same row a QA code, G, is located in the qflag_tmax colunm. I can do this one QA code and one variable at a time using,

```
df2<-within(df,tmax[grepl("G",qflag_tmax)]<-"NA")
```

but I am looking for code to handle all QA codes and multiple variables with out creating additional objects.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grepl` is used for pattern matching since here you want to perform an exact match use `%in%`.

```
df$tmax[df$qflag_tmax %in% c("G","I","O","S","Z","T")] <- NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
    mutate(tmax = replace(tmax, qflag_tmax %in% c("G","I","O","S","Z","T"), NA))
```